# Sql Order By ... using `Case When` for different Ascending, Descending, and Custom Orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sort product by discount on certain condition

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 0
    THEN table.id END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @Orderby = 2
    THEN table.id END ASC,
```

I want to do something like below as I don't have discount column in table

```
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 4
THEN (100-((table.price/table.oldprice)*100) as discount END ASC
```

but it throws an error - how can I sort by discount?

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Remove `as discount`. It is in a wrong place altogether (inside expression), and you cannot alias an expression in `order by` as it makes no sense.

Comment: incorrect syntax near the word as

Comment: I removed as discount but giving error near end

Comment: Count the parentheses.

Comment: No parenthesis are correct,If i remove that last condition its working well

Comment: it says 'cae' instead of 'case'

Comment: Hazaart ,I didnt get u?

Comment: There was a typo but it's OK now.

Comment: You have 3 opening parentheses and 2 closing in `then` part of case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are quite a few problems, e.g. You can't alias a calculation field in an order by, and you'll need to escape your table name, fix the `cae`, and count the parenthesis.

Also, since it seems you just want to `CASE` on a single variable, you can move the `@OrderBy` out to the top of the CASE, like so:

```
SELECT * from [table]
ORDER BY 
    CASE @OrderBy
        WHEN  0
            THEN [table].id -- ASC
        WHEN 2
            THEN [table].id * -1 -- DESC
    ---I want to do something like below as I don't have discount column in table
        WHEN 4
            THEN (100-([table].price/[table].oldprice)*100)
    END
```

[SqlFiddle Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41859/1)

As an aside, if you need to dynamically change the `ASC` or `DESC` of a column, you can use a hack like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884884/conditional-sql-order-by-asc-desc-for-alpha-columns) by multiplying by -1.

(Also note that `ORDER BY CASE ... END ASC, CASE ... END ASC` will set the first and then second orderings ... this doesn't seem to make sense given that `@OrderBy` can only have a single value)

Comment: And actually i have used asc and desc in order by                       CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 20
  THEN (100-(table.price/table.oldprice)*100)END DESC,

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me you need something similar to this

```
select * from TableName where someCondition >100
  order by
    case when @OrderBy = 'AirlineService'
      then AirlineService END desc,
    case when  @OrderBy = 'SomeMore'
      then  MyOtherColumn  end
GO
```

If you not have a coulmn then you can not sort with that. Please read this [Microsoft Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188385%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) Please keep in mind - specifies the sort order used on columns returned in a SELECT statement. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: You are welcome, one more small thing, column name that you will specify in order by will always retrieved from even that column is not specified in the select list. You can check this behavior with execution plan.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41859/1 By (StuatLc) solved my problem ,thanks for ur support

Answer (score 3):

Don't calculate the discount in the `ORDER BY` clause but in the `SELECT`

```
SELECT *, (100-(table.price/table.oldprice))*100 as discount
FROM table
```

...

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 0
THEN table.id END ASC,
CASE when @orderby=2
THEN table.id END ASC,
CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 4
THEN discount END ASC
```

Comment: Hazaart Actually we can calculate discount in order by,Above solution worked(StuartLC's) for me You can view demo on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41859/1