# Bind sort attribute in SELECT Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For a SELECT query with a sort order I prepare this statement :

```
$direction = 'DESC';
$project_id = 1;

$query = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT text FROM marker WHERE project_id = :project_id ORDER BY time :direction');
$query->bindValue(':project_id', $project_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(':order', $direction, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$success = $query->execute();
```

But it fails. So I prepare this statement :

```
$query = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT text FROM marker WHERE project_id = :project_id ORDER BY time '.$direction.'');
$query->bindValue(':project_id', $project_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$success = $query->execute();
```

And it works.

Can one not bind a ORDER attribute ? 
How to bind ORDER attributes properly ?

Comment: See manual `[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]` you cannot pass direction with variable

Comment: But you can use [CASE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207954/using-variables-for-asc-and-desc-in-order-by) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884884/conditional-sql-order-by-asc-desc-for-alpha-columns)

Comment: I just had a  quick view into the links. It looks quite complicated for a simple approach. As I stated above, when I use the $direction var in the SELECT statement it works. But I thought its bad coding concerning sql injections. So my question is how to do it right ?

Comment: you can use IF statement in PHP but it will duplicate code  or pass variable to expression which will be used to order like links I provided above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express what you want with a `case` statement.  Here is a relatively simple expression:

```
order by (case when :order = 'DESC' then time end) DESC,
         time ASC
```

Comment: It works perfect, thanks. I accept this answer because I can bind the order attribute now and I learned the case statement, which I did not know before.